# Unable to monitor event loop AND Wait for app to idle

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xctestcase

I am writing UITest cases for my app using XCTest. The app makes several server calls on the home screen. I could not navigate to the next screen. Automation often stays idle for 1 min or even more than that with the message

> Wait for the app to idle

or

> Unable to monitor event loop

Is there a way to make the app execute my test cases breaking this ???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**I have set argument in UI test class**

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments = ["NoAnimations"]
app.launch()
```

In my Appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I made a check

```
 NSArray *args = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].arguments;
    
    for (NSString *arg in args){
        if ([arg isEqualToString:@"NoAnimations"]){
            [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:false];
        }
    }
```

So now all over my app, there won't be any animation and my app is no more blocked. This reduced my automation time from ***25mins to 2mins.***

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to help you use one of these two methods below. The first awaits an element appears on the screen. The second element is awaiting hittable. But in any case these methods help you, maybe you can use the method sleep(param). Like `sleep(5)`. Waits for 5 seconds

```
import XCTest

class BaseTestCase: XCTestCase {

    func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement, timeout: NSTimeInterval = 60,  file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate,
                                evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)
        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout) { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                let message = "Failed to find \(element) after \(timeout) seconds."
                self.recordFailureWithDescription(message, inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func waitForHittable(element: XCUIElement, timeout: NSTimeInterval = 70, file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "hittable == 1")
        expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)

        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout) { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                let message = "Failed to find \(element) after \(timeout) seconds."
                self.recordFailureWithDescription(message,
                                                  inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope to have helped in some way

Comment: Thanks for finding time to help me. The element is still hittable and exists but again it waits long time with same "Wait for app to idle" message. Sometimes I do see this message ----  " App animations complete notification not received, will attempt to continue".